# WCF Soap Service +IP Filter, Client refused with proxy

Tags: wcf, soap, proxy

There is a Third party `WCF` `SOAP` service hosting behind a `firewall` with certificate authentication.
While doing some testing on this , **When i making a request with out setting proxy to null**,

```
             HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServiceUrl);

            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", ServiceAcion);

            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";

            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";

            webRequest.Method = "POST";

            webRequest.Proxy = null;
```

**i am getting 403 exception**, but if `IPAddress` is already white listed ,Why `IIS` refusing the connection.

Standard Definition of Proxy is

```
A proxy server is a server (a computer system or an application) that acts  
as an intermediary for requests from clients seeking resources from other servers
```

Bear with me on this Stupid question.What is happening under wrappers ?